# Java, String to JTable

Tags: java, string, swing, jtable, jsch

I have a program that using JSCH runs a command on a server and get the following results out

```
   rcpt  7554   Jan-21 01-03:43:27       ? /usr/bin/Program
ncuser2  7202   Jan-21 01-04:22:08       ? /usr/bin/Program
    lyn  6277   Dec-17 36-02:14:51       ? /usr/bin/Program 10.15.1.104:0.0
    lyn  6268   Dec-17 36-02:15:17       ? /usr/bin/Program 10.15.1.104:0.0
```

These results are stored in one string.

What I need to do is convert/Output these results into a JTable.

What I cant work out is how to get what's in the single string above into multiple cells of a JTable in Swing so it looks like this

```
  User | PID | Launch | Runtime    | TTYP | Program |
  -----------------------------------------------
  rcpt | 7554| Jan-21 |01-03:43:27 | ?    |/usr/bin/Program
ncuser2| 7202| Jan-21 |01-04:22:08 | ?    |/usr/bin/Program
    lyn| 6277| Dec-17 |36-02:14:51 | ?    |/usr/bin/Program 10.15.1.104:0.0
    lyn| 6268| Dec-17 |36-02:15:17 | ?    |/usr/bin/Program 10.15.1.104:0.0
```

The main issue I am having is finding a way of splitting the string, I want to do it on space, looking at this. Even if I could split it into variables for every space I could possibly work it out but at the moment I don't have a clue!

Comment: Did u get your answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it as below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dataStr = "rcpt  7554   Jan-21 01-03:43:27       ? /usr/bin/Program\n"
                + "ncuser2  7202   Jan-21 01-04:22:08       ? /usr/bin/Program\n"
                + "lyn  6277   Dec-17 36-02:14:51       ? /usr/bin/Program 10.15.1.104:0.0\n"
                + "lyn  6268   Dec-17 36-02:15:17       ? /usr/bin/Program 10.15.1.104:0.0\n";

        String rows[] = dataStr.split("\n");


        Vector<Vector<String>> dataVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
        for (String row : rows) {
            row = row.trim();  //UPDATE
            Vector<String> data = new Vector<String>();
            data.addAll(Arrays.asList(row.split("\\s+")));
            dataVector.add(data);
        }

        Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>(2);
        header.add("User");
        header.add("PID");
        header.add("Launch");
        header.add("Runtime");
        header.add("TTYP");
        header.add("Program");

        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(dataVector, header);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DemoFrame");
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }
```

## OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: I had just found split as well as a command, now going to have a look at this and see if its doing as i want ill get back to you in 5

Comment: Not quite sure whats going on, its close but some things up its outputting the table with everything shifted along to the Right one cell, so Users are in PID Field, and so on any ideas?

Comment: Unsure what the proper format maybe? currently im directing the output to a ByteArrayOutputStream then doing String myResults = myByeStream.toString(); then using the string to put the results into the vector

Comment: can you debug it by setting debug points.Also you can use Sysout.If possible post the output of sysout too.....

Comment: Appears that data[0] is blank just has a " " as there is a space at the start of the string, so data[0] is the space, would i be able to resolve this using format?

Comment: Yes have a look at my update. Added :
row = row.trim();  //UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

1. split("\n") for the lines
2. split("\s+") for the cells